# C# Will reflection create multiple instance of a singleton in my assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection, singleton

I am creating a c# based automated testing framework and have configuration files that link test case methods and class names to requirement IDs. The framework will create a TestPlan that is a list of multiple test cases that will executed one after another.

Since there are thousands of testcases (and more all the time) I want to call these classes and methods by reflection, but I am concerned that these methods will create singleton instances of supporting classes that will hang around after the method returns that won't be reused when the next test method is called by reflection.

My question is: will each call use the same static instance in the assembly? Or will each call create a new instance of the singleton? Without reflection in the mix it is a simple answer, but with it ... I am not certain.

Example: I will call SomePageTestCases.TestcaseMethod1() by reflection below. This creates a static instance of CurrentPage which contains the Page object used by the TestMethod. After the Testcase returns, what happens if I call another TestMethod in another class by reflection? Does the CurrentPage.Instance persist and will it be used by the newly called test method? Or will it original be orphaned in the assembly and a new static instance of CurrentPage be created by the new test methods call?

```
namespace Framework.TestCases
{
    public class SomePageTestCases
    {
        public bool TestCaseMethod1()
        {
            return (CurrentPage.Instance.Page as SomePage)?.DoSomething() ?? false;
        }
    }
}

namespace Framework
{
    public class CurrentPage
    {
        private object TopLevelControl;

        private static CurrentPage _instance;
        public static CurrentPage Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new CurrentPage());

        private Page _page;

        public Page Page
        {
            get
            {
                if (_page == null || _page.Name != GetCurrentPageName())
                    _page = GetCurrentPage();
                return _page;
            }
        }

        private CurrentPage()
        {
            //hooks the top level control of the system under test.
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private static string GetCurrentPageName()
        {
            //return the page name of the current page from the TopLevelControl.
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private static Page GetCurrentPage()
        {
            //Searches the TopLevelControl for the current PageObject and returns it.
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

namespace Framework.Base
{
    public abstract class Page
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public object PageObject { get; private set; }

        protected void LoadPage(string pageClassName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            //Name = something;
            //PageObject = something;
        }
    }
}


namespace Framework.Pages
{
    public class SomePage : Page
    {
        public bool DoSomething()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public SomePage()
        {
            LoadPage("SomePage");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened _when you tried it_? There's not enough context in your question; without a good [mcve], we don't know exactly what you're doing with reflection. If you are really just calling methods with reflection, they will behave the same as usual. But reflection can be used to do all sorts of bad/incorrect things. No one can say what your code does, without seeing your code. So far, you're the only one here who's seen your code. And you're in a great position **to just try it**.

Comment: Problem is that I am in the development phase and I am looking at the software architecture diagram for the unimplemented classes. This is a feasibility issue of the design.

Comment: Creating a new AppDomain for each test will prevent all possible side effects between tests. But without more information it's difficult to decide whether this is feasible or not.

Comment: _"This is a feasibility issue of the design"_ -- then your question is far too open-ended and broad to be appropriate on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I take it by your response that the provided example and code I provided at your request wasn't enough context. I really can't go any further  without breaching company policy. Can you recommend a site where there are experts on reflection that are allowed to have open discussions?

Comment: Calling `TestCaseMethod1` with reflection will be the same as a direct call. But if this is generally true for all your test cases is not possible to determine for us.